# iPhone App: You enter the score and it works but how do i limit it?

Tags: iphone, numeric-keypad

My iPhone app works fine, and all parts work fine, however it lets you score certain things, but how can i limit the score for example at the minute you could rate item x "609573095730" but i only want to to allow the user to score between 0 and 100, how would i do this, i can imagine it to be very simple, but i can't seem to work it out my self.

Side note:
Score is inputed via numerical keypad (like the phone one)

Comment: If you only want the user to be able to score between 0 and 100, why not just use a UISlider that clips to the nearest 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you receive the input, parse it to NSInteger or NSNumber and then check if it is between 0 and 100

The other solution is using a UIPickerView from 0 to 100:)